# force plot onto next frame without erasing the previous plot (using packages plotrix, bpDir, circular)

Tags: r, plotrix

I want to plot the following using the `bpDir` package (that also includes `circular` and `plottrix`).

```
library(bpDir)
require(circular)
require(plotrix)
data(fisherB12c)
CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics")
```

The above works fine, as it should.  Let me now try and get two figures side by side.

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))

CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics")
CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics")
```

The second plot simply wipes out the first plot and puts the second plot in its place, thus not quite what I want. How do I get these to be side-by-side? I tried

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))

CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics")
frame()
CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics")
```

but that wipes out the first plot on the left. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions on how to get around this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `patchwork`:

```r
library(patchwork)

p <- wrap_elements(full = ~CircularBoxplot(fisherB12c, template="geographics")) 
p + p
```

[image]

Comment: Btw, can I use something like this to put the right figure on top of the left (of course, in this case, it would not make a whole lot sense, but let us say the right one had an argument of shrink = 2?

Comment: Yes, you can move the plots around however you want using patchwork. There are many examples in the docs or on Stack Overflow